# Getting “attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property on detached entity” after trying to pass alambda expression into the Where clause

Tags: ef-core-2.1

I'm using Entity Framework Core 2.1.2 with lazy loading enabled and am performing a query. If I try to pass a lambda expression I always get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Error generated for warning
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning:
>   An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'Children' on
>   detached entity of type 'ParentProxy'. Lazy-loading is not supported
>   for detached entities or entities that are loaded with
>   'AsNoTracking()'.'

Here some code :

```
public class User
    {
        public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; } = new HashSet<UserRole>();
    }

public class UserRole
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public int RoleId { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

My db context:

```
 public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
                services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connection"));
                });
    }
```

That's how it works:

```
_userRepository.Table.Where(user => user.UserRoles.Any(userRole => userRole.RoleId == 10)).ToList()
```

And that's how it doesn't:

```
_userRepository.Table.Where(user => condition(user)).ToList()
```

Where the condition is:

```
Func<User, bool> condition
```

Example:

```
Func<User, bool> result = (user) => user.UserRoles.Any(role => role.RoleId == 10)
```

I'm so sorry for bad formatting. But I hope that you understand my problem.

Comment: The problem is the `Func<…>`. EF queries best work with `Expression<Func<…>>`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you. I thought that it doesn't work, but it works!